# Unity C# variable not working inside OnCollisionEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game that is about basically rolling a ball and when you hit gameover object it's gameover, when you hit goal object it's goal (and maybe you'll be navigated to next stage or whatever), and here I want algorithm it will be ignored when you hit gameover object after you hit goal object, so once you hit to the goal object you'll win the stage.

Here the C# code, I set variable `goaled` and tried to change the variable to "true" when you hit the goal object, and when only if `goaled == false`, when not yet you goaled, you'll be lose. But the code doesn't work, as a expected result it shouldn't log "gameover" after I goaled, but actually it will.

So, how can I modify the code to work as expected? Thanks.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class tmp03 : MonoBehaviour
{

    bool goaled = false;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision otherObj)
    {

        // bool goaled = false;

        if (gameObject.name == "goal" && otherObj.gameObject.name == "ball")
        {
            Debug.Log("goal");
            Debug.Log(goaled);
            goaled = true;
            Debug.Log(goaled);
        }
        if (gameObject.name == "gameover" && otherObj.gameObject.name == "ball" && goaled == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("gameover");
            Debug.Log(goaled);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If you look at the documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html they are also using the vars like you did. I think it is something wrong with the namings. Have you tried to set goaled to public? That way you can track the changes during the game in the editor and see if it changes if you score a goal. What are the values returned by the debug log, does it successfully change the goaled var onCollisionEnter?

Comment: @Holger yes, I also tried `public bool goaled = false;` but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe you forgot the rigidbody component. For this to work, at least one of the objects has to have a rigidbody component. If you don't want to add rigidbodies, I suggest using onTriggerEnter and switching the isTrigger property to true on the colliders of goal and gameover objects.

Comment: @MustafaCemKobal I have rigidbody component for "ball" object. OnCollisionEnter itself is working well, the logs will be shown when the ball object hit to the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand from your code, specifically from the lines
`gameObject.name == "goal" && otherObj.gameObject.name == "ball"` & `gameObject.name == "gameover" && otherObj.gameObject.name == "ball" && goaled == false`, it seems to me as if you are adding this script to both the **goal** and **gameover** gameobjects.

These are TWO DIFFERENT script instances. They will not share the `goaled` property between them.
If you want to track only ONE `goaled` property, you should add the script only once (in this case, to the player) and inverse the if conditions. Have the ball be the primary gameObject, and the gameover object and goal as the `otherObj`